Meaning of $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log|z_{n+1}|}{\log|z_n|}=1$
It is given that, $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log|z_{n+1}|}{\log|z_n|}=1$$
where $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of zeros of an entire function $f$.
Question: I want to know about the growing behavior of zeros of $f$. What can be said  regarding the distribution of zeros of an entire function satisfying the above equation.
I understand that $\log|z_n|$ and $\log|z_{n+1}|$ grow nearly at the same rate as $n\to\infty$. But I don't know the growing behavior of the sequence $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
If anyone explains what is going inside of that equation, will be helpful for me. Thank you.

Do you mean that any entire function with infinitely many zeros has this property or are you asking what else can be deduced about an entire function if it has this property?

No @quarague I don't want to know anything about $f$, my curiosity is what can we say about the growth of the zeros from that equation above? This means, I want to know how the zeros are distributed as $n\to\infty$?
